# endfloat - copy figures instead of moving them

Tags: endfloat

I've recently been playing with the package `endfloat` as part of a processing chain for tables and figures from journal papers.

I was wondering if it is possible to make the package work its usual magic (creating the `.fff` and `.ttt` files, which I need) without actually doing anything to the document (not including these files, not changing the way the figures appear in the main document).

I've looked through the documentation, but didn't find anything to this end. Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: If it's just about getting the files, then maybe it would be an option to run the file with `endfloat`, collect the files, and then run without `endfloat` to restore the document?

Comment: If this was just for myself, that's exactly what I would do (for the testing setup I use right now, that *is* what I do). But since this is supposed to become a package to be used by other people and also automatized to some extent, a less hacky solution would be preferred.

Comment: this (and your other question) are actually feature requests. So why don't you open an issue end the gitlab repo: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/endfloat

Comment: Very good suggestion, I'll do that, thanks!

Comment: Update: axel seems to no longer be maintaining the package.